# Error while importing minitab file into R

Tags: r, import, mtp

I was using the foreign package in R to import the MTP file, but it only shows file read error. I already set up the default directory, but it does not work. I would really appreciate if I could get some help. Thank you in advance.

```
library(foreign)

d44<-read.mtp("PERAGGR.MTP")
```

[Here is the file that I was using](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uJ4WbaaYLD3pDSAPlMwKfPTXHp6YFJEG/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: In `foreign` alone, there are at least 33 `stop` locations, most (all?) unique. Which error do you find? Can you provide a sample of the MTP file that we can test with? Otherwise it's rather difficult to guess and/or reproduce your error.

Comment: > library(foreign)
> read.mtp("PERAGGR.MTP")
Error in read.mtp("PERAGGR.MTP") : file read error

Comment: That was my result.

Comment: Here is the file that I was working with

Comment: Errors, sample data, and code should really be in the question itself: comments can be skipped by readers and, if there are a lot of comments, they can be hidden. Best to keep the question "whole". Thanks.

Comment: I just added the file in the post.

Comment: `file read error` is not a problem with `foreign`, it's likely to be an OS-based error.

Comment: If at all possible (and it should be possible here), it's generally better to *not* use links in questions: links can go stale, and when they do this question becomes unreproducible. (And we strive to keep questions complete as much as feasible/reasonable.) In this case, perhaps you can include the contents of an MTP file with only 1-2 components instead of the 5 plus extra lines?

Comment: The `?read.mtp` help page says: "This function was written around 1990 for the format current then. Later versions of Minitab appear to have added to the format." It's actually a text file so you should be able to read it with `readLines`.The header of the mtp file offered is: "Minitab Portable Worksheet P1.1             2007 523 Rel    15.0               ."

Answer (score 0):

The read.mtp function is fairly ancient. And since that file is actually an ASCII file, just read it with `readLines:

```
d44<-readLines("~/Downloads/PERAGGR.MTP")
head(d44)
# ============== top of output==================
[1] "Minitab Portable Worksheet P1.1             2007 523 Rel    15.0               ."
[2] "%      3      1    109      0 Study                                            ."
[3] " 1.000000000E+00 2.000000000E+00 3.000000000E+00 4.000000000E+00 5.000000000E+00"
[4] " 6.000000000E+00 7.000000000E+00 8.000000000E+00 9.000000000E+00 1.000000000E+01"
[5] " 1.100000000E+01 1.200000000E+01 1.300000000E+01 1.400000000E+01 1.500000000E+01"
[6] " 1.600000000E+01 1.700000000E+01 1.800000000E+01 1.900000000E+01 2.000000000E+01"
```